I have a framer-motion based Counter component. I want it to start the account once the component is in view
I have a framer-motion based Counter component. I want it to start the account once the component is in view. Currently, The count happens on page-load, the only thing that happens is the component jumps up once in view:
export default function Counter({ from, to }: CounterProps) {
    const nodeRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const node = nodeRef.current;

        const controls = animate(from, to, {
            duration: 1,
            onUpdate(value) {
                if (node) {
                    node.textContent = Math.floor(value).toLocaleString() + "+";
                }
            },
        });

        return () => controls.stop();
    }, [from, to]);

    return (
        <motion.p
            variants={{
                visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
                hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 },
            }}
            initial="hidden"
            whileInView="visible"
            className="font-black text-6xl absolute top-[70%] text-center items-baseline justify-center  grayscale filter  object-contain rounded-2xl"
            ref={nodeRef}></motion.p>
    );
}

I also tried using reac-intersection-observer but it does not even render:
"use client";
import { animate } from "framer-motion";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

interface CounterProps {
  from: number;
  to: number;
}

export default function Counter({ from, to }: CounterProps) {
  const nodeRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({
    triggerOnce: true, // Only trigger the animation once
    threshold: 0.5, // Adjust the threshold as needed
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const node = nodeRef.current;

    if (inView) {
      const controls = animate(from, to, {
        duration: 1,
        onUpdate(value) {
          if (node) {
            node.textContent = Math.floor(value).toLocaleString() + "+";
          }
        },
      });

      return () => controls.stop();
    }
  }, [from, to, inView]);

  return (
    <p
      className="font-black text-6xl absolute top-[70%] text-center items-baseline justify-center grayscale filter object-contain rounded-2xl"
      ref={ref}
    ></p>
  );
}

